# Get base64-encoded string from ReadOnlySequence<byte>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

Given `ReadOnlySequence<byte>`, how to get its base64-encoded representation?
There's [`ReadOnlySpan<Byte>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=net-7.0#system-convert-tobase64string(system-readonlyspan((system-byte))-system-base64formattingoptions)) overload, but sequence is... a sequence of spans, not a single span.

I know, that it's possible to make an array from sequence, but this is what I want to avoid: I use [`RecyclableMemoryStream`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream) and trying to avoid extra memory allocations.

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something which can keep state as you pass in different blocks of bytes. That thing is a [`ToBase64Transform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.tobase64transform?view=net-6.0).

Annoyingly, none of the methods on it take a Memory or ROS (apart from the `async` ones) -- they're all array-based. I guess you could have a scratch array which you copy chunks into, then pass those chunks to `ToBase64Transform`, but at that point you might as well just use `Convert.ToBase64String` on each chunk and concatenate the results.

You could pass `ToBase64Transform` to a `CryptoStream`. You could then call `Stream.Write(ReadOnlySpan<byte>)`, but that's implemented to [copy the span into an array](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Stream.cs,922) (and `CryptoStream` doesn't override this), which is what you're trying to avoid.

However, `CryptoStream` [does override `WriteByte`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography/System/Security/Cryptography/CryptoStream.cs,277), so that might be your best bet.

Something like:

```cs
using var writer = new StringWriter();
using (var stream = new CryptoStream(writer, new ToBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
{
    foreach (var memory in readOnlySequence)
    {
        if (MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray(memory, out var segment)) 
        {
            stream.Write(segment.Array, segment.Offset, segment.Count);
        }
        else
        {
            var span = memory.Span;
            for (int i = 0; i < span.Length; i++)
            {
                stream.WriteByte(span[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

string result = writer.ToString();
```

---

At this point, though, it's looking like it might be neater to just use [`Base64.EncodeToUtf8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.text.base64.encodetoutf8?view=net-6.0) and a `StringWriter` yourself, manually...

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get your point about `Base64.EncodeToUtf8` and `StringWriter`. I see, that, probably, it is possible to encode `ROS` span-by-span, but how `SW` is related to this task?

Comment: `Base64.EncodeToUtf8` outputs bytes representing UTF-8 characters. `StringWriter` takes UTF-8 bytes and turns them into a string. That's what the `StringWriter` is doing in the `CryptoStream` example -- `CryptoStream` is outputting UTF-8 bytes and pushing those into the `StringWriter`, and the `StringWriter` is turning those into a string

Comment: I'm still thinking about solution, but marking your answer as accepted. At least you've pointed me to direction to investigate, thanks.

Comment: @Dennis how did it work out for you? Performance wise.